# One of my USB slots don't work but the others are fine

Tags: usb, windows-8.1

When I try to plug anything into one of the USB ports on my computer, it doesn't register plugged in (I don't get the `Installing Driver Software` message, if it's a USB I don't see it in explorer, etc).

All other ports work fine.

Comment: Is the port attached (soldered) to the motherboard? ...or is the port connected to the main board with a cable?

Comment: Soldered to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your motherboard is broken. Its USB slot may have just burnt out. Look for any obvious signs that it's broken (black, bent, etc). If that's the case, pretty much the only way to solve this is to get a new motherboard.

Comment: I'd get an external powered usb hub if you need the slots.

Answer (score 0):

That port is probably dead and you fixing it would void your warranty if you had any.  Most motherboards have additional USB headers so unless you really need that port I suggest ignoring the broken one and using one of the spare headers.  If your motherboard is still under warranty and your can live without the use of your computers for weeks there is a chance they might fix it for you.

The only other **safe** answer is get a new motherboard.

If you were experienced with a soldering iron, and the motherboard was out of warranty you might be able to unsolder the old one and replace it with a new one.  **This requires more patients,skill, and time than most people have.**